# Filtering array of objects if specific key contains search term

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to filter through an object with multiple key/value pairs by a specific key. It appears that the code I've written is searching the entire object regardless of the key...

If key `name` contains the search term, return the search term.

**Array of Objects:**

```
export const someArrayOfObjects = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Something' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Another' },
  { id: '3', name: 'Lets do one more' },
]
```

**Search:**

```
const searchResults = someArrayOfObjects.filter((o) =>
      Object.keys(o).some((k) => o[k].toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
    );
```

So if I search `"Something"`,  I only want it to loop through `name` to search for that term...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `Object.keys` loop.

```js
const someArrayOfObjects = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Something' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Another' },
  { id: '3', name: 'Lets do one more' },
];
let key = 'name';
let searchTerm = 'th';
const res = someArrayOfObjects.filter(o => 
   o[key].toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

similar to iota's, you don't need to create the extra array with Object.keys.
just loop/check every item inside the original array with the 'name' key.
you can also try to make it more reusable like below.

```
const someArrayOfObjects = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Something' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Another' },
  { id: '3', name: 'Lets do one more' },
];

const search = function (anyArray, searchTerm) {
  return anyArray.filter((obj) => {
    if (obj.name === searchTerm) {
      return obj.name;
    }
    return false;
  });
};

const case1 = search(someArrayOfObjects, 'Something');
console.log(case1);
```